# Laravel eloquent postgres search in jsonb field

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, jsonb

In my database I have a "data" jsonb field that's jsonb and contains data like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1000,
    "item": "foo",
    "location": "test#1"
  },
  {
    "id": 1001,
    "item": "bar",
    "location": "test#1"
  },
  {
    "id": 1002,
    "item": "foo-bar",
    "location": "test#2"
  }
]
```

Now in Laravel I'm currently searching through the whole field like this:

```
->where('data', 'ilike', '%'.$searchInput.'%')
```

But I want to search for the specific item:

```
->whereJsonContains('data->item', $searchInput)
```

But that doesn't give me the results I expect.

Does anyone know how to search only for a matching "item" using eloquent?

Comment: Please share your desired result in this case

Comment: I want the model to be found that matches exactly, so if $searchInput is "foo" I would want this model to be found, but if the search is "1001" I wouldn't want the model with the data array above to be found.